# Git pull request not working with cronjob

Tags: git, shell, cron

I am very new to coding, can someone help me on how I can successfully execute `git pull` with cron job.

I did write a Shell script that has git pull as follows and when I run the shell script on the terminal it does work.

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /Users/xplain/testing/UI
git pull
cd testing
python -m unittest XplainTestRunner.XplainTestRunner
```

But with my cron job it's not working. My cron job is as follows

```
11 16 * * * /Users/xplain/automation.sh >> /Users/xplain/script_output.log 2>&1
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Is your `automation.sh` script marked as executable?

Comment: Well, it's possible to run a shell script that isn't executable by passing it as an argument to `sh`, which isn't shown here.